# cmake tool, what is the difference between --build and -B options?

Tags: cmake

`cmake --help` shows the following info:

```
-B <path-to-build>           = Explicitly specify a build directory.

--build <dir>                = Build a CMake-generated project binary tree.
```

Can someone explain the difference?

Comment: The option `-B` is for [Generate a Project Buildsystem](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#generate-a-project-buildsystem) flow of `cmake` invocation. The option `--build` is part of [Build a project](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#build-a-project) flow. That is, given options simply cannot co-exist in the same `cmake` invocation.

Answer (score 4):

CMake is commonly used is like this:

```bash
cmake -S my/project/source/dir -B my/build/dir # more options ...
cmake --build my/build/dir
```

The first line sets up a build in `my/build/dir`, it *configures* and *generates* the build. The result is something that can be consumed by a platform-specific tool, e.g. a Makefile, build.ninja or VS solution file.

The second line triggers the actual build. Whatever tools was set up in the previous step (make, ninja or Visual Studio) runs and compiles the project. You could substitute `сmake --build` with the respective tool. `cmake --build` has the added advantage that it is platform independent.