# cmake and make with -j flag produces error in docker

Tags: docker, cmake, makefile, dockerfile

In my dockerfile, I have this:

`RUN cmake -j$(nproc) -S . -B build`

When I run it, it produces this error: `CMake Error: Unknown argument -j16`

I have `cmake > 3.12`. What is the issue here? It runs perfectly when I do it outside of the docker in the host machine.

Comment: Did you configure the project before using that command?

Comment: I'm surprised that works for you outside of docker.  `-j` is not a valid option to `cmake`.  it IS a valid option to some build commands that cmake can generate project files for.  But in order to ask cmake to run one of those commands you need the `--build` option.  Something like: first run `cmake -S . -B build` then run `cmake --build build -- -j$(nproc)`

Comment: @StephenNewell, Sorry, I am new to docker and cmake. How can I configure the project? It worked without any configuration in the host.

Comment: @MadScientist It produces the same thing when I try your suggestion.

Comment: "It produces the same thing" - It cannot produce the same `CMake Error` because everything after the `--` is passed to a build tool (which is NOT CMake), and a build tool doesn't generate errors titled "CMake Error".

Comment: Btw, [`-j` is a valid argument to `cmake --build`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-build-j) but only in combination with the `--build`option. To configure the project, the command as shown in the question (without `-j`) is used. See [here for the difference between configuration and build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76090747/cmake-tool-what-is-the-difference-between-build-and-b-options/76091148#76091148).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the `-j` option with `cmake` then try something like this:

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq cmake g++

COPY . .

RUN cmake -S . -B build
RUN cmake --build build -j$(nproc)
```

Loosely speaking, the first time `cmake` is run it generates the build directory and writes a suitable `Makefile`. The second time `cmake` is run with the `--build` argument it actually does the build. It effectively uses the `make` command and that accepts the `-j` argument, specifying the number of concurrent processes. Obviously for the example code below this is overkill but will make a difference for a large project.

Files required to complete the example:

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(project)

add_executable(executable main.cpp)

install(TARGETS executable DESTINATION bin)
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, CMake world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Logs for relevant part of build process:

```
Step 4/5 : RUN cmake -S . -B build
 ---> Running in 1fceddb78831
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /build
Removing intermediate container 1fceddb78831
 ---> 73e99ae72e90
Step 5/5 : RUN cmake --build build -j$(nproc)
 ---> Running in ac07d5ad7e0e
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/executable.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable executable
[100%] Built target executable
Removing intermediate container ac07d5ad7e0e
 ---> e196a5849f75
```

Check executable.

[image]

Comment: The preexisting dockerfile has something like this: `RUN cmake -S . -B build`, then `RUN make -j$(nproc) -C build` and `RUN make -j$(nproc) DESTDIR=./dist -C build install`. Are the last to commands equivalent to `RUN cmake --build build -j$(nproc)` as in this example?

Comment: Yes, `RUN make -j$(nproc) -C build` does the same thing as `RUN cmake --build build -j$(nproc)`.

Comment: The second command (`RUN make -j$(nproc) DESTDIR=./dist -C build install`) doesn't work with my example because there is no `install` target in the `Makefile` generated by CMake. I have updated my answer to include an install target. The second `make` command should work now too.